# Error with icons in UE4 AR(Kit) development for iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, windows, augmented-reality, unreal-engine4

I want to compile the ARKit project for iOS on Windows. I intalled VMWare with Mac OS 10.15 Catalina. Also I installed XCode and accepted the license agreement. But when I'm starting compiling I get this error:

P.S. here is smaller log (it has only 1 line of error instead for every icon)

```
   UATHelper: Packaging(iOS): 2019-11-25 20:42:57.845 IBCocoaTouchImageCatalogTool[917:9978] Unable to get image dimensions for file:///Users/damir/UE4/Builds/DESKTOP-DOB5C9P/D/Projects/UE4_Projects/ARTatar/Intermediate/IOS/Resources/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/IPhoneIcon40@3x.png
   UATHelper: Packaging(iOS): 2019-11-25 20:42:58.072 IBCocoaTouchImageCatalogTool[917:9998] CoreThemeDefinition: Unable to create image for file:///Users/damir/UE4/Builds/DESKTOP-DOB5C9P/D/Projects/UE4_Projects/ARTatar/Intermediate/IOS/Resources/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/IPadIcon20.png
UATHelper: Packaging(iOS): /* com.apple.actool.errors */
UATHelper: Packaging(iOS): /Users/damir/UE4/Builds/DESKTOP-DOB5C9P/D/Projects/UE4_Projects/ARTatar/Intermediate/IOS/Resources/Assets.xcassets: error: Distill failed for unknown reasons.
UATHelper: Packaging(iOS): /* com.apple.actool.document.notices */
UATHelper: Packaging(iOS): /Users/damir/UE4/Builds/DESKTOP-DOB5C9P/D/Projects/UE4_Projects/ARTatar/Intermediate/IOS/Resources/Assets.xcassets:./AppIcon.appiconset/[][ipad][76x76][][][1x][][]: notice: 76x76@1x app icons only apply to iPad apps targeting releases of iOS prior to 10.0.
UATHelper: Packaging(iOS): /* com.apple.actool.compilation-results */
   UATHelper: Packaging(iOS): /Users/damir/UE4/Builds/DESKTOP-DOB5C9P/D/Projects/UE4_Projects/ARTatar/Binaries/IOS/Payload/AugmentedImages.app/AppIcon20x20@2x.png
UATHelper: Packaging(iOS): /Users/damir/UE4/Builds/DESKTOP-DOB5C9P/D/Projects/UE4_Projects/ARTatar/Binaries/IOS/Payload/AugmentedImages.app/Assets.car
UATHelper: Packaging(iOS): /Users/damir/UE4/Builds/DESKTOP-DOB5C9P/D/Projects/UE4_Projects/ARTatar/Intermediate/IOS/Resources/assetcatalog_generated_info.plist
   PackagingResults: Error: Distill failed for unknown reasons.
UATHelper: Packaging(iOS): [Remote] Downloading C:\Users\DAM1R\AppData\Roaming\Unreal Engine\AutomationTool\Logs\D+Unreal+Engine+4+UE_4.23\UBT-AugmentedImages-IOS-Development_Remote.txt
UATHelper: Packaging(iOS): Total execution time: 196,01 seconds
UATHelper: Packaging(iOS): Took 198,6845239s to run UnrealBuildTool.exe, ExitCode=7
UATHelper: Packaging(iOS): UnrealBuildTool failed. See log for more details. (C:\Users\DAM1R\AppData\Roaming\Unreal Engine\AutomationTool\Logs\D+Unreal+Engine+4+UE_4.23\UBT-AugmentedImages-IOS-Development.txt)
UATHelper: Packaging(iOS): AutomationTool exiting with ExitCode=7 (7)
UATHelper: Packaging(iOS): BUILD FAILED
   PackagingResults: Error: Unknown Error
```

And full log is here:
https://uengine.ru/forum/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=67350

Answer (score 0):

Updating Mac OS and XCode fixes this.

Updating to 11 XCode and 10.15.2 Mac OS Catalina, for instance, fixes this issue.